# What can cause Tomcat to ignore a web application

Tags: tomcat7

Tomcat is not loading my web application. I get a "404 Page not found", when I try to open it.

So far, I tried:

- deployed war(myapp.war) to CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory
- created myapp.xml in webapps directory with Context element
- restarted tomcat
- I even tried hitting index.jsp under WEB-INF folder in my war
- I also tried adding Context element in server.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with a very simple case. Onces you got this working, you can extend it.

1. Undo your changes to the tomcat configuration, perhaps start with a fresh tomcat installation.
2. create one folder for your web application directly below the tomcat webapps folder
3. create a simple index.html file in that folder
4. create a subfolder called WEB-INF
5. create a web.xml file in that folder:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

   <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

   <web-app>
       <display-name>My webapp</display-name>
       <description>My webapp</description>

       <welcome-file-list>
           <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
   ```

**Important**

1. Make sure to use the correct upper/lower case spelling of all file and directory names: index.html and web.xml completed in lower case. WEB-INF in upper case.
2. .jsp files need to be outside the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I don't this is working, there are default examples deployed in webapp which will server index.jsp file.  I want to edit those applications and say point path "/" to my application instead, that is the reason why I added Context element, <Context path="/" docBase="/home/User/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/myapp.war" debug="0" privileged="true" reloadable="true"/>

Comment: @user903887 You should delete the example because they may be in conflict (and there have been security issues discovered in old version). The simplest way to mount your application into /, is to call the subfolder for your application below webapps "ROOT" (Note: upper case).

Comment: thanks Hendrik, i removed all examples and deployed my application as ROOT.war which under webapps. This is hacky but works for now